# Can I make modifiable part of the web address passed through in a Google Spreadsheets =ImportHtml function?

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

Wondering if there is a way to modify part of the web address (passed through in double quotes) in a `=ImportHtml` function in Google Spreadsheets?

eg.

`www.schoolgrades.com/tom`
`www.schoolgrades.com/jerry`
`www.schoolgrades.com/daffy`

I just want to be able to do this for a whole list of names without having to edit the `ImportHtml` function.  I haven't been able to get it to work yet but am sure it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

You could concatenate the URL from another cell. Let's say you have 3 columns, where each column header is a name:

```
Tom | Jerry | Daffy
```

... and that you want row 2 - X to be populated by the `importHTML` function. Then, in row 2 column A, you would write

```
=importHTML("http://www.schoolgrades.com/" & A1)
```

This will be interpreted as `=importHTML("http://www.schoolgrades.com/Tom")`.
If you drag the formula across row 2, the formula will automatically be updated so that row 2, column B will be `=importHTML("http://www.schoolgrades.com/" & B1)` etc.

In case you wondered, the `&` [is the string concatenation operator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/15748/21583).