# A function opposed to SUMIF?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a huge list of matches between clubs and I want to calculate the goals for and the goals against.

I could find a way to calculate the goals for, using:

```
=SUMIF (A35:A46, "Liverpool", B35:B46) + SUMIF(D35:D46, "Liverpool", C35:C46)
```

The team being calculated the number of goals is organized like

Newcaste United 1 2 Liverpool
(where Newcastle is `A1`, NewcastleGoals is `B1`, LiverpoolGoals `C1` and Liverpool, `D1`).

What I need is to find a function that is opposed to `SUMIF` so I can calculate the goals against Liverpool like `SUMIF`, instead of collecting the result cell by cell with the sum function.

Basically, the logic would be like the first example, but ignoring "Liverpool" and calculating all of the other strings:

> =SUMIF (A1:A38, if not Liverpool, B1:B38) + SUMIF(D1:D38, if not Liverpool, C1:C38)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `<>`?

```
=SUMIF (A1:A38, "<>Liverpool", B1:B38) + SUMIF(D1:D38, "<>Liverpool", C1:C38)
```

Not that the `<>`-symbols should be inside the quotation marks.

Comment: "<>" stands for "different than"? I'm struggling to find documentation. Gonna try it. Thank you.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! :D

Comment: Yeah, or. "Not Equal to"
Here's documentation on SUMIF: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093583
It's not directly telling you to use '<>', but it's hinting you to use standard operators. 
From what I can tell Google doesn't seem to have created any extensive documentation covering everything in Spreadsheets. You can read more here (including the basic operators etc.): http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/15748/29712
You're very welcome :)

Comment: By the way, if my answer did answer your question, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the remind, I didn't know how to do it - just learned it. Oh, and thank you VERY MUCH for the links. I started studying C# a few weeks ago and I'm in love with Microsoft documentation, so one can just guess my horror trying to use Google Spreadsheets without it. :D

Comment: No problem! Yeah, I can imagine! I started using Google Spreadsheet  last week. I have actually used scripts more than formulas, but I think much is rather similar to Excel. SUMIF, for example is used in the same way: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx

Comment: Yeah, the most help that I got to use the Google Spreadsheets is from Microsoft documentation too, but I hit some walls, like this one. Cheers!