# Add 1 if there is data in cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet of data which lists the inspection results of schools, in which I have a column that states the result or is empty if that particular school has not yet been inspected.

I want there to be a cell which returns the number of schools that have been inspected. I assume that the best way to do this is to check whether or not the 'inspection result' cell has anything in it, and if it does add 1 to this 'total inspected' cell. I've tried writing an IF statement but it isn't working:

```
=IF(
   OR(
     'Indiviual FS Data'!D2:D174 === 'Good (2)',
     'Indiviual FS Data'!D2:D174 === 'Outstanding (1)',
     'Indiviual FS Data'!D2:D174 === 'Requires Improvement (3)', 
     'Indiviual FS Data'!D2:D174 === 'Inadequate (4)'
   )=,
   C3+1, C3
 )
```

This may not make sense as you can't see the spreadsheet.

I have some very minor knowledge of programming concepts but I don't have any experience with this or similar in Excel.

Answer (score 4):

I would just use

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D174, "<>")
```

It counts all cells in the range which aren't empty.

About your formula:

- You cannot use the `===` operator (or `==`). You only use `=`.
- You don't use a single quote (`'`) for strings, use double-quotes (`"`).
- You have one extra `=` after your ending `OR` parenthesis.
- You cannot use a range in a comparison in the way you do, compare only one cell.

Comment: What does `<>` do in this context?

Comment: It means "Not equal to", and since nothing follows, it means "Not equal to nothing". It counts cells that aren't empty.
You could write `"<>Hi"` to look for cells not containing `Hi`.

Comment: Ah, that's great. Could you supply a link to the documentation for the `<>` operator? I don't think I have seen it before.

Comment: Google has a rather limited documentation on it's formulas. I'm not sure if there's any documentation about that, read more here:
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15727/complete-reference-documentation-for-google-spreadsheets-formulae/15748

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Great! I'd be pleased if you were to mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to count the number of rows (schools), then subtract the number of blank cells.

Given the following spreadsheet:

```
    A             | B
1 | School name   | Inspected date
-----------------------------------
2 | School 1      | 2/24/2014
3 | School 2      | 
4 | School 3      | 1/5/2014
```

... the following formula will give the number of schools that have been inspected:

```
=ROWS(B2:B4) - COUNTBLANK(B2:B4)
```

<sup>For your spreadsheet, you would use `=ROWS(D2:D174) - COUNTBLANK(D2:D174)`</sup>

The `ROWS` function gives the number of rows in the given range (`3`). The `COUNTBLANK` function gives the number of blank cells in the given range (`1`). So `=3-1` will give the result `2`.

I have set up [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdHlodUVBeTdGQ2NRaWltWVdGWVN5S1E&usp=sharing) to demonstrate.

See the [Google Spreadsheet Function list](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en) for details on how the functions work.

Comment: Is this preferable to my answer in any way? It seems to to me to be doing the exact same thing, only with an extra function.

Comment: No, you're probably right. I wrote it because I didn't understand the `<>` in your answer, and wanted to supply something less cryptic. But your comment to your answer clarified it nicely.